# Get SharePoint 2013 Taxonomy Term by TermName

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, taxonomy

I am looking for a way to use Javascript to Query Taxonomy.js, to get a Term based on Term Name (I don't have ID available on page).

Only option that I am able to find is to retrieve all terms in the TermSet, loop through each term to match the name.

This works, but is causing performance issue. I am looking for a way to get the term directly, without looping through all.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to cobble this together.

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var session = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
var termStore = session.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();

var parentTermId = 'd89595cf-7d0d-4f19-8e14-8b8b05efb7de'; // Some parent term
var parentTerm = termStore.getTerm(parentTermId);

// arguments are termLabel, language code, defaultLabelOnly, matching option, max num results, trim unavailable
var terms = parentTerm.getTerms(series,1033,true,SP.Taxonomy.StringMatchOption.exactMatch,1,true);

context.load(terms);
context.executeQueryAsync(
function(){
   //print child Terms
   for(var i = 0; i < terms.get_count();i++){
       var term = terms.getItemAtIndex(i);
       console.log(term.get_name());
       console.log(term.get_description());

   }

}, 
function(sender,args){
  console.log(args.get_message());    
});
```

If you know one parent term's guid you can use that and then get a specific term below that. In our case the parent term only has one level of children, so I haven't checked if it searches children of children.

There is also the TermSet.getTerms() method which takes a labelMatchingInformation object as its argument. Here is [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312487.aspx) and [a blog about it](https://davemcmahon81.wordpress.com/2014/05/06/sharepoint-2013-javascript-api-sp-taxonomy-labelmatchinformation/). I couldn't get the lmi to work, but in the blog he seems to be apply it directly to a taxonomysession and I think it is supposed to be applied to a termset, so maybe that is the difference.